# Internet Information Services (IIS) 10 Express Error: Cannot read configuration file

Tags: iis, configuration, visual-studio-2019, iis-express-10

Visual Studio 2019 can't run any project and display this error.How to resolve this error?

Comment: Edit the question to include a report, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/vs-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to `C:\Users\.....\Documents\IISExpress\config`, delete all config files and rebuild project, then run it.

If it doesn't work, try to uninstall IIS Express in control panel and re-install it.(you can download it in Web PI)

Answer (score 0):

This issue anatomically fix when i update my visual studio 2019.